# Full span(width) view in n'th index of LazyVGrid with 2 columns SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid

I have a LazyVGrid with 2 columns in my ContentView.
I want to add full width item on every n'th index of the grid.
In this code snippet I am trying to add full width item only in the 2nd  position for testing.
How can I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

```
`LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())], alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
        if index == 2 {
            Text("Full Width Item")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding()
        } else {
            Text("Regular Item")
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 50)
                .background(Color.green)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}`
```

[image: I am tring to achieve something like this.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using a `GeometryReader` to get the width of the `LazyVGrid` to calculate the cell sizes.

The regular cells are the same as in your sample code, but for the full width cell, I'm using a `Color.clear` and overlaying it with the large cell, and then using another `Color.clear` to fill space for the second cell in the row.

```
struct ContentView: View {
        
    let spacing: CGFloat = 20
    let columnCount = 2
    
    var columns: [GridItem] {
        Array(repeatElement(GridItem(.flexible()), count: columnCount))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center) {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { index in
                    if index == 2 {
                        Color.clear
                            .frame(minHeight: 100)
                            .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("Full Width Item \(index)")
                                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                                    .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                                    .background(Color.gray)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .cornerRadius(8)

                            }
                        Color.clear
                    } else {
                        Text("Regular Item \(index)")
                            .frame(width: cellWidth(for: proxy.size))
                            .frame(minHeight: 100)
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func cellWidth(for size: CGSize) -> CGFloat {
        (size.width - ((CGFloat(columnCount) - 1) * spacing)) / CGFloat(columnCount)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. overlay(alignment: .leading) is only available from iOS 15, but my app has deployment target iOS 14.

Comment: Ashley Mills , I am actually using this LazyVGrid inside a VStack (because I have other items above the LazyVGrid) which is embedded in a Scrollview. if I add GeometryReader inside a Scrollview, it won't scroll properly..

Comment: Scrolling works fine if you put the `ScrollView` inside the `GeometryReader`, although that doesn't help with the iOS 14 problem.

Comment: In the screenshot you added, How to add a full-width Item in the 10 position? which is in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize `Sections` and their footer or header which is imho cleaner solution than what Ashley is proposing.

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100))], content: {
        ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { index in
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 100)

            if index != 0 && index % 6 == 0 {
                Section {

                } header: {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .frame(height: 50)
                }

            }
        }
    }).padding(.horizontal)
}
```

Result:

[image: grid]